# How to solve the not declared errors in the code

Tags: c++

Here is a code to count number of vowels but I have error that tell me the strlength is not declared .

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
   int vow_cnt=0; 
   char name[15]; 
   cout<<"Enter a name"<<endl; 
   cin>>name; 
   for(int i=0;i<strlength(name);i++) 
   { 
      if(name[i] == 'a' || name[i] == 'e'||name[i] == 'i'||name[i] == 'o'||name[i] == 'u') 
      { vow_cnt++; } 
      cout<<"Total Vowels in the string are=>"<<vow_cnt<<endl; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yes. Looking at that code it appears that the declaration of `strlength` is indeed missing.

Comment: I believe the problem is on line 3.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You can see that the entire program is composed of `strlength` repeated 0 times.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't posted any code. Anyway, i believe you are looking for `strlen`, not strlength. The definition of `strlen` is on the cstring header:

```
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char arr[] = "bleh";
    int length = std::strlen(arr);
}
```

So your fixed code should be:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 

using std::strlen; 
using std::cin; 
using std::endl; 
using std::cout; 

int main() { 
   int vow_cnt=0; 
   char name[15]; 
   cout<<"Enter a name"<<endl; 
   cin>>name; 
   for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++) 
   { 
      if(name[i] == 'a' || name[i] == 'e'||name[i] == 'i'||name[i] == 'o'||name[i] == 'u') 
      { vow_cnt++; } 
      cout<<"Total Vowels in the string are=>"<<vow_cnt<<endl; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: No idea how you got -1'd. I like your answer better than Luchian's.

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int vow_cnt=0;
char name[15];
cout<<"Enter a name"<<endl;
cin>>name;
for(int i=0;i<strlength(name);i++)
{
if(name[i] == 'a' || name[i] == 'e'||name[i] == 'i'||name[i] == 'o'||name[i] == 'u')
{
vow_cnt++;
}
cout<<"Total Vowels in the string are=>"<<vow_cnt<<endl;
}
}

Comment: This is my code but I try to upload I cannot KK what is the problem in strlength?????

Comment: Mmmm, yes? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen. Surely he downvoted it, since he thought strlen is not in the std namespace.

Comment: @Hams The problem is that there is no such thing as `strlength`. Both answers give you a feasible solution.

Answer (score 2):

What is `strlength`? `std::string` has a member method `length` and you should use that:

```
std::string s = "this is the string";
size_t len = s.length();
```

Or perhaps you're thinking of `strlen`?

Since this is C++, I suggest you stick with `std::string` and use `length`, and not `const char*` and `strlen`.

Change this:

```
for(int i=0;i<strlength(name);i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
```

Also, not that your code doesn't account for upper-case vowels.